# Adding a suffix widget to CupertinoTextFormFieldRow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

Is there a way to add a `suffix` widget to `CupertinoTextFormFieldRow` without it losing the CupertinoForm style? I would like to see something like:

```
CupertinoTextFormFieldRow(
  prefix: const Text('Email'),
  placeholder: 'Enter your email',
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter your email';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onSaved: (value) {
    // Save the email value
  },
  // Add suffix widget
  child: CupertinoTextFormField(
    suffix: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Do something when suffix is pressed
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.info_outline),
    ),
  ),
)
```

This wouldn't work of course because `CupertinoTextFormFieldRow` doesn't have a `child` property.